# How to Convert audio .mp3 file to String and vice versa?

Tags: android, audio-streaming

Is it possible to convert an audio mp3 file to a string data for sending data to the server, 
and server will return a string data to my app i want to convert that data to mp3 file and play audio.

I am using this code to convert mp3 file to string data

```
public static String readFileAsString(String filePath) throws java.io.IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    String line, results = "";
    while( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
    {
        results += line;
    }
    reader.close();
    return results;

}
```

i don't know how to get back my mp3 file from converted strind data.

If possible then how ? anybody help me.

Or any other solution for this requirement tell me: i want to pass audio and video files to server and get back from the server to use in app.

Comment: you should not transfer binary files as strings.

Comment: then what is the solution to pass mp3 file to server and get back from server.

Comment: http://pure-java-mp3-encoder.blogspot.in/

Comment: Don't know the reason behind string conversion. However, just asking, why not upload the file itself with a track with database and getting back with a streaming?

Comment: @vini if there is any other possibilities, give link i will try to do that.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy are you asking me a link about string conversion or file upload?

Comment: ya, actually i tried like this what i was uploaded in question, but i am unable to retrieve data from converted data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use Base64.encodeToString()   try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-4.wav");
byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);

String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);                                       
Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Encoded: ", encoded);

byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
Utilities.log("~~~~~~~~ Decoded: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

try
{
    File file2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/hello-5.wav");
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
    os.write(decoded);
    os.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}



public class FileUtils {

    /**
     * Instances should NOT be constructed in standard programming.
     */
    public FileUtils() { }

    /**
     * The number of bytes in a kilobyte.
     */
    public static final long ONE_KB = 1024;

    /**
     * The number of bytes in a megabyte.
     */
    public static final long ONE_MB = ONE_KB * ONE_KB;

    /**
     * The number of bytes in a gigabyte.
     */
    public static final long ONE_GB = ONE_KB * ONE_MB;



    public static String readFileToString(
            File file, String encoding) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
    }



    }

}
```

Comment: what i have to convert by using this

Comment: i again edited the code just check it out again i have merge fileutil class in my code

Answer (score 0):

```
Error:(49, 41) error: cannot find symbol method readFileToByteArray(File)
```

i think you have not defined that method in FileUtils, did you ?

i have resolved this issue by changing the code as follows:

```
//byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
```