# How to upload video to php server in android (same as whatsapp) and then show it?

Tags: android

I am working on a chat project .I want to send video or audio or image to php server(same as whats app) and also i want to show it at receiver side .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use Base64 Encoding concept which will send audio or video or image as string and retrieve as you need..

[Base 64 Encode Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360403/base-64-encode-and-decode-example-code)

[Base 64 Encode for Audio Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13819097/how-to-convert-audio-mp3-file-to-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: No. In mysql DB they have to define column type as BIGINT(2000) like that. So It can handle, Because I had implemented is Base64 for a PHP server